# Mere presence of implicit conversion makes the program compile despite never being applied

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicit-conversion, type-parameter, type-constructor

Consider method `f` which is parameterised by a type constructor `F[_]` and a proper type `A`

```
def f[F[_], A](v: F[A]) = v
```

Lets try to apply it to `new Bar`

```
scala> class Bar
class Bar

scala> def f[F[_], A](v: F[A]) = v
def f[F[_], A](v: F[A]): F[A]

scala> f(new Bar)
       ^
       error: no type parameters for method f: (v: F[A]): F[A] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Bar)
        --- because ---
       argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
        found   : Bar
        required: ?F[?A]
         ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : Bar
        required: F[A]
```

This errors as expected as `Bar` is not of the right shape.

Now lets add an implicit conversion from `Bar` to `List[Int]`

```
scala> implicit def barToList(b: Bar): List[Int] = List(42)
def barToList(b: Bar): List[Int]

scala> f(new Bar)
val res1: Any = Bar@56881196
```

This compiles, however notice that implicit conversion did not seem to have actually been applied because the runtime class of `res1` is `Bar` and not `List`. Furthermore, the compile-time type of `res1` is `Any` and not `List[Int]`. Looking at output of `-Xprint:typer` we see something like

```
val res1: Any = f[Any, Nothing](new Bar())
```

where we see the following inference happened

```
F[_] = Any
A = Nothing
```

as opposed to

```
F[_] = List
A = Int
```

and we see that no conversion actually happened, that is, we do not see something like

```
f(barToList(new Bar()))
```

Why did the mere presence of implicit conversion make the program compile whilst no implicit conversion was actually applied? Note that when being explicit about type parameters it works as expected

```
scala> f[List, Int](new Bar)
val res2: List[Int] = List(42)
```

Comment: *"This errors as expected as `Bar` is not of the right shape."* Actually `Bar` can be considered as having the right shape since it's `Id[Bar]` (where `type Id[A] = A`). It's just too tricky to infer higher-kinded types. With hints everything works: `f(new Bar: Id[Bar])` or `f(new Bar: List[Int])`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin But `Id` isn't defined already, is it? Wouldn't it be "easier" to infer it to be a `List[Int]`?

Comment: btw in Dotty this works https://scastie.scala-lang.org/yQ5ibiClSumSrgX1uv2rLQ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've noticed this issue before, and I think it can be tracked down to [this code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/9371ef72ae0e58d350a1d2aa733ef2ba237a4bc7/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Infer.scala#L579-L584) in the compiler:

```
  // Then define remaining type variables from argument types.
  foreach2(argtpes, formals) { (argtpe, formal) =>
    val tp1 = argtpe.deconst.instantiateTypeParams(tparams, tvars)
    val pt1 = formal.instantiateTypeParams(tparams, tvars)

    // Note that isCompatible side-effects: subtype checks involving typevars
    // are recorded in the typevar's bounds (see TypeConstraint)
    if (!isCompatible(tp1, pt1)) {
      throw new DeferredNoInstance(() =>
        "argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type" + foundReqMsg(tp1, pt1))
    }
  }
  val targs = solvedTypes(tvars, tparams, varianceInTypes(formals), upper = false, lubDepth(formals) max lubDepth(argtpes))
```

As I understand it, the problem is that the `isCompatible` check looks for implicit conversions, but doesn't keep track of whether one was required or not, while `solvedType` just looks at bounds.

So if you don't have the implicit conversion, `isCompatible(Bar, F[A])` is false and the `methTypeArgs` call throws the `DeferredNoInstance` exception—it won't even consider `Any` as a candidate for `F`.

If you do have the implicit conversion, `isCompatible(Bar, F[A])` is true, but the compiler promptly forgets that it's only true because of the implicit conversion, and `solvedTypes` picks `Any` for `F`, which is allowed because of Scala's weird special-case kind-polymorphism for `Any`. At that point the `Bar` value is perfectly fine, since it's an `Any`, and the compiler doesn't apply the conversion it found in `isCompatible` (which it forgot that it needed).

(As a side note, if you provide explicit type parameters for `f`, `methTypeArgs` isn't called at all, and this discrepancy between `isCompatible` and `solvedTypes` is irrelevant.)

I think this must be a bug in the compiler. I don't know whether someone's already reported it (I just spent five minutes looking and didn't see it).